# Insert into database facebook posts in a list using python and executemany

Tags: python, mysql, facebook, web-scraping, executemany

I am using python, oursql and facebook SDK to scrape the data from Facebook and put it into the database. I wrote a function and manage to get the data in a list, but executemany puts into the database only first row. I don't know where the error is. Thanks for the help in advance.
This is my function:

```
def get_posts(page_id, follow_account_id):
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(get_facebook_access_token()) 
posts = graph.get_connections(page_id, 'posts')
facebook_posts = list()
should_finish = False
while True:  # keep paginating 
    try: 
        with get_db_connection() as cursor: 
            for post in posts['data']: 
                #print post
                if datetime_from_iso(post["created_time"]) < until_time:
                    should_finish = True
                    break
                try:
                    user_id, post_id = post["id"].split("_")  # "133174387208_10154860725907209
                    link = "https://www.facebook.com/{0}/posts/{1}".format(user_id, post_id)
                except:
                    link = None
                facebook_posts.append((3, post_id, None, None,  0, post.get("from").get("name"), post.get("from").get("id"), post.get("from").get("name"), filter_using_re(post.get("message", None)), link, follow_account_id)) 
                print facebook_posts


            cursor.executemany(post_insert_query, facebook_posts)
# get next page 
            posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json() 
    except KeyError:  
        break
```

Prepared statement:

```
post_insert_query = u'''
INSERT INTO post(
    social_media_id, external_id, post_time, post_date, related_post_id, poster_name, poster_id, title, content, post_url,
    follow_account_id)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
```

Comment: What is the value of the variable `post_insert_query`? I don't see it defined so I'm not sure what SQL you are executing.

Comment: @aychedee it is prepared statement and it is imported. This is just a part of the code that have to gather facebook posts and insert data into database. I just edited my question.

Comment: Please indent correctly.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you for noticing. It was typo. I edited my question. Indentation is not a problem. Still not working.